# How to switch focus automatically when max length reached in QML TextField?

Tags: qml

In order to do that, I understand I need to use some if condition like the one below. But it looks like I did a mistake!

Is the problem in the `if condition` or in the position, where should I include it?

```
    Grid {
    x: 5
    y: 3
    rows: 5
    columns: 20
    spacing: 10

    Repeater {
        id: rpt
        model: 50

        TextField {
            width: 28
            height: 50
            color: "green"
            text:{ "0000";  

    if(rpt.itemAt(index).text.length ==4)nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()



                }
            font.pixelSize: 12

           Keys.onEnterPressed: nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()

            validator: IntValidator {
                bottom: -256
                top: 256
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to react when the text changes inside the `TextInput`, so in the body of the `textChanged` signal handler:

```
TextField {
    width: 28
    height: 50
    color: "green"
    onTextChanged: {
        if (text.length === 4) {
            nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
        }   
    }
}
```

See more on [JavaScript Expressions in QML Documents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about OnTextChanged option! this is amazing !

Comment: You are welcome. [A signal is emitted whenever the value of a QML property changes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#property-change-signal-handlers). This is a basic behavior or a QML application, I advise you to take time to read in detail the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtqml-index.html) before pursuing the development of your application, it will save you a lot of time and energy and you will learn a lot. Also don't forget to mark the answers as accepted here when they solved your problem :)

Comment: Can I receive signal from  validator, I want to change the focus also when the user enter the max possible answer! ?

Comment: You could give an id to the validator `id: validator` and then change your current  condition to compare the text to the top value `if (Number(text) === validator.top)`. Everything about accessing QML object properties is available to read in the documentation pages http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html

Comment: Great Thanks !!